# Why are my Chrome fonts so small?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, appearance

[image: Small fonts on Chrome]

the majority of the sites I visit look like the above example, extra tiny small.
Google chrome on windows 7

- no plugins
- tried everything from resetting windows fonts to custom zoom, which makes everything worse.
- Uninstalled chrome, installed it again, and also tried with Firefox. now the fonts look even worse.

Comment: are you migrating from Firefox (or any other browser) to chrome? If so, take a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/804949/why-does-firefox-interpret-100-zoom-differently-to-other-browsers). Also, try `ctrl+0` which will take you back to 100% zoom level, if you have had it changed it before!

Comment: No, but I even tried that, and it has no effect on the problem

Comment: What resolution are you using, and when was the last time the texts appeared fine in this system. Is the text distorted only on Chrome, if not, do you have [ClearType](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-text-easier-read-cleartype#1TC=windows-7) enabled?

Comment: see this: http://superuser.com/questions/803601/text-size-suddenly-got-bigger-on-all-sites-on-google-chrome/803650#803650

Comment: 1920x1200, the text last time appeared clear some months ago, the text is distorted on both Chrome and FF (which I installed AFTER chrome and only to check with the problem). ClearType was disabled, turned it on, still nothing.

Comment: I tried /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1 but has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

So a friend came over and was checking with the css of this and other websites. Here's how we fixed it :
Whenever there was 'Helvetica' set as default font in the css, it used mine version to render the text. In my case Helvetica was corrupted font and had to delete it through CMD/SAFE MODE . Now everything looks sweet and Arial-ish :)