# Why do I have blurry application on reboot only?

Tags: graphics-card, windows-8.1, reboot

I am witnessing a very weird situation on my Asus Laptop, running on Windows 8.1.

Basically, if I shutdown my computer and restart it all works fine.

However, if I reboot the computer using the reboot button from the Windows charms, the following happens:

- Windows shuts down
- I see the Asus "welcome" screen of Republic of Gamers
- The logo disappears and I end up on a black screen which simply won't go away.

Now, I have noticed that, by pression on the power button, I could get the notebook to go to sleep, wake it up and I would end up on the login screen. Yes, BUT, once I log in, some application appear really blurry like if it was not the right resolution or something.

I guess there is some drivers issue going on there, but I can't quite figure out what's happening.

Do you have an idea?

**Example**

Firefox looks like this:

[image]

Should look like this, and looks like this if I do a shutdown and then start again:

[image: Firefox OK]

**Setup**

I have a Geforce GTX 660M graphic card, and I tried to uninstall completely the drivers using a cleaner and then reinstall it. It didn't change the problem. Could it be windows update that tries to install something on reboot (is there a windows update queue or something?)?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I tried to make it as explicit as possible with the pictures, please let me know if you think something else could be more approriate

Comment: Does this only occur in Firefox or are there other applications involved? Also, is the first image zoomed on purpose or it appears as is?

Comment: The first step in the troubleshooting process seems clear, uninstall your display drivers, then install them again.  What GPU are you using ( Intel, Nvidia, AMD )?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I haven't zoomed at all, just used the snipping tool. It does it for Firefox, Chrome, Excel, Bitdefender ... I can remove it on some of them by disabling DPI settings, but even Windows' interface is blurry.

Comment: @Ramhound I added the config in the question.

Comment: Seeing as though this affects more than Firefox, I'll leave [this](http://superuser.com/q/804949/228536) question for reference (essentially Firefox picks up the DPI setting in Windows and uses it with zoom). Either DPI settings are coming in the way or you have a resolution that doesn't match well with your screen size.

Comment: I'm not well versed in these sorts of things (graphics issues) but a search with "Geforce GTX 660M blur" showed me a suggestion to disable FXAA globally on the NVIDIA control panel.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard The thing is, it's not a settings problem. Something I prevent the computer to restart properly right? because I have to make it sleep and waken everytime at reboot otherwise I stay on the black screen.